# replace strings with part similar with str_replace

Tags: r, string, replace, str-replace

I have a data.frame with a column products  who i want to replace a especific products who are write in different way but they same products. I want replace de product names (INTER, INTERNAC, INTERNACION) to INTERNACIONAL, i try do:

I have a dataframe with a product column. I want to replace products that were written in different ways but that are the same product ex:
(INTER, INTERNAC, INTERNACION) replace to INTERNACIONAL
I tried to do it like this:

```
tb_j$variante<- str_replace(tb_j$variante,"INTER","INTERNACIONAL")
but return this way.

INTERNACIONALNAC    
INTERNACIONALNACION
```

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the whole word by adding `\\S*` i.e. zero or more non-whitespace

```
library(stringr)
tb_j$variante<- str_replace(tb_j$variante,"INTER\\S*","INTERNACIONAL")
```

Or use

```
tb_j$variante<- str_replace(tb_j$variante,"INTER[A-Z]*","INTERNACIONAL")
```

---

The issue was that the 'INTER' was only getting replaced by the replacement word while the other characters that are after 'INTER' remained as such